# "Choppy" look on circular designs

Tags: adobe-illustrator

My circular designs are coming out "choppy"--that is, instead of being a neatly rounded circle, at least one point (top-most, bottom-most, left-most, right-most) in the circle comes out as if it's partly a straight line.

By circular design, I mean creating logos and icons that are within a circle--a circle created by AI's `Ellipse Tool`.

Inside AI, I see that it's a perfect circle, even if I significantly zoom in. Whenever I save my designs for web, however, I get this "choppy" look. I am saving my images to a PNG-24 file--as that seems to be the highest quality. (File -> Save For Web..)

I have tried adjusting the artboard of my design--ensuring that it is larger than the design itself, but I get the same problem nonetheless. How do I fix this?

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of the problem?

Comment: If you save a vector image as a bitmap, then you get aliasing. It's in the nature of a bitmap, since it's constructed from pixels.

Answer (score 1):

Increase the Resolution in AI's export to PNG option to something over 1000px at least.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I've found that saving vector files from Illustrator as .svg format gives better results, if you're using those images for the web. You might try that. I was having the same issue with a logo I built in Illustrator; when I saved it as .svg instead of .png, the quality was much better.